# Sending emails to member group when an entry is updated

Tags: add-on, email, entry, notification

Does anyone know of a (free) add-on that will send a custom email message to a member/member group when an entry is updated?

Or does anyone know of a way to do this with the standard EE setup?

UPDATE.
As suggested, MX Notify Control does what I'm asking. However it appears to let you notify a group when the status of any entry in a channel changes.

After further thought I have realised I need to be able to notify particular members when a particular entry is updated (i.e. any field has changed rather than just the status - although I could work it with just the status if necessary)

I'm thinking RSS could be an option here however my user base is not going to be familiar with RSS so email would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do it with MX Notify Control and it's free:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control

I've never tried it before so, consider it an option vs a recommendation if that makes sense :)

And just for the sake of being thorough there is also Postmaster though, it of course isn't free:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster

Comment: I'm just looking at MX Notify Control actually. Realising that I need to update my question. Would like to look at Postmaster but since this is for a proof of concept/personal project I don't really want to purchase an add-on if I can possibly avoid it. It may be an option though assuming it will do what I need.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything out there other than something custom or Postmaster which might require using it's API. I was thinking about Better Workflow for a minute but, realized that it only sends out emails when an entry needs approval though, I could be wrong. And well, it's another commercial add-on.

Comment: @foamcow I built Postmaster to fill a gap in the existing EE functionality. I spent nearly 6 months doing R&D on how to solve all these problems, and finally came up with a viable API over the next 6 month. Postmaster can do what you want out of the box, and gets you setup and running in a matter of minutes. You can even send email with any service. Email support@objectivehtml.com if you have specific questions. While Postmaster is $65 dollars (on Devot:ee), it solves all these problems well and really capable of doing some awesome stuff.

Comment: That sounds very interesting then. I don't think I'll use it for this project as I'm just trying to demonstrate a principle to someone and it's unlikely I'll end up building the site. It's just a local dev project for now. However I CAN see a use for Postmaster with some other projects that are coming up. Very interesting, thank you.